# Alpha blending between two objects

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have two objects in my scene , a rectangle and a circle.

rectangle is 1 unit in z axis and circle is 0 units in z axis.

rectangle has opacity of 50 and the circle has opacity of 100

Why is the alpha of rectagle reducing the alpha of the circle even though the circle has opacity of 100.

This is how the alpha looks like.[image]

This is the blend mode i am using.

```
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible explanation is, that the rectangle is "darker" than the circle.

When alpha blending is set by

```cpp
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Then the formula for the final color is

```non
color_dest = color_dest * (1-alpha_source) + color_source * alpha_source
```

Lets assume the color of the circle 1.0. and the alpha channel of the circle is 1.0, too. The circle is drawn first. The content of the target buffer is black (0, 0, 0, 0).
When the circle is drawn then blending is applied:

```non
color_dest   = color_dest   * (1-alpha_source) + color_source * alpha_source
(1, 1, 1, 1) = (0, 0, 0, 0) * (1 - 1.0)        + (1, 1, 1, 1) * 1.0
```

The rectangle has a color of 0.5 and and an alpha channel of 0.5, too. Again blending is applied:

```non
color_dest               = color_dest   * (1-alpha_source) + color_source         * alpha_source
(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75) = (1, 1, 1, 1) * (1 - 0.5)        + (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) * 0.5
```

So the final color at the fragments where rectangle covers the the circle is (0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75). The "darker" rectangle darkens the circle.

Answer (score 2):

If you want different equation  for RGB color and different for Alpha you can use.

```
  glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```